# c++: передача значение из константной структуры в неконстантную (выдается ошибка)

Tags: c++, указатели, c++11, c++14, константа

Подскажите как исправить следующую ошибку:

Есть структура данных:

```
struct CMyData
{
     int m_data;
};
```

Есть константный указатель на эту структуре

```
const CMyData* ptr = _get();
```

Хочу записать в другую структуру указатель на данные из первой

```
myData2.m_ptr = &ptr->m_data;
```

И получаю ошибку

> error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'const CMyData::int *'
>   to 'CMyData::int *'

Исправляется отменой константы, т.е. так:

```
CMyData* ptr = _get();
```

Но хочется придерживаться минимальной функциональности - я же не собираюсь менять сам `ptr`, поэтому и объявил константой.

Comment: Ну объявите во второй структуре поле `m_ptr` не как `int*`, а как `const int *`...

Comment: `const CMyData* ptr` — это не «константный указатель», а  «указатель на константную структуру»

Comment: Harry, честно говоря никогда не встречался с таким - т.е. в структуре будет константный член и при этом менять я его смогу только из конструктора при инициализации и при описанной мной выше ситуации?

P.S. понял свою ошибку, Harry спасибо

Comment: @Fat-Zer именно это и есть причина моего недопонимания :) Теперь понял, действительно `const` относился к другой части.

Comment: @Zhihar, ответ сам сможешь написать?

Comment: Это что же за версия компилятора вы дала вам такое странное сообщение об ошибке "cannot convert from 'const CMyData::int *' to 'CMyData::int *'"??? Visual Studio в такой ситуации скажет "cannot convert from 'const int *' to 'int *'". Никакого упоминания 'CMyData::'.

Comment: @AnT Visual Studio 17